# JERSEY - Accessing Generic List in Response

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey

Im facing isssue in getting Jersey Generic List in client response. I need to get it as Entity for some reason.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="list")
@XmlSeeAlso({RESTDomain.class})
public class JAXBContainer<T> {
    private List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();

    public JAXBContainer() { }

    public JAXBContainer(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="items")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getItemsSize() {
        return this.items.size();
    }
```

above is my Generic List to the resopnse

```
 @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response getREST(){  
        RESTDomain domain = new RESTDomain();
        domain.setName("Adams");
        domain.setPlace("Zurich");
        List<RESTDomain> restDomains = new ArrayList<RESTDomain>();
        restDomains.add(domain);        
        JAXBContainer<RESTDomain> jAXBContainer= new JAXBContainer<RESTDomain>(restDomains);        
        GenericEntity<JAXBContainer<RESTDomain>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<JAXBContainer<RESTDomain>>(jAXBContainer){};


        return Response.ok(genericEntity).build();

    }
```

Im returning the container with genericEntity. I know with just List inside genericEntity i can get my Entity at my client but the problem is i need to Use my JAXBContainer for some reason.

```
 @Test
            public void restGet() throws JAXBException{     
                ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();        
                client = Client.create(cc);
            String baseURI ="http://localhost:3555/SampleREST/rest/sample";
                    WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseURI);         
                    JAXBContainer<RESTDomain> jAXBContainer= webResource.get(new GenericType<JAXBContainer<RESTDomain>>(){});         
                     System.out.println("response:: "+jAXBContainer.getItemsSize());
    }
```

My problem is im getting the response as JAXBContainer with GenericType as desired but the size of container is  0. What am i missing here? do i have to Use any marshalling and unmarshalling Mechanisms.

But When i request this URI in browser i get the well formed XML, But it fails in client or do we have any other ways to extract entity in client. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you're setting the accept content type anywhere on the client.
Try with: webResource.accept("application/xml")